# Executing jar file through php

Tags: java, php, web, jar

I have a jar file that I am attempting to execute through php using

```
exec('java -jar DUapi.jar '.$USER.' '.$PWORD);
```

When I do that however, it does not output a text file to the directory like it's supposed to.  If I execute the jar on the command line, however, it works properly.  If I print the result code, the result is "Array".  Could this be an issue with permissions?

Comment: Could you share the classes in the jar? There is not much here for us to help you. A permissions issue is possible, but there could be other things too.

Comment: What does "the directory" mean? Usually it will write it to the current working directory, so the directory where the php process is started (not the .php file)

Comment: I can't share the jar - it's not something I wrote.  But like I said, if I execute it manually from the command line everything works properly.  When I say "the directory", I mean the directory that the jar is location in.  However, both the php file and the jar are in the same directory.